# unity2D gameObject tag does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**I'm new on Unity2D.Although I set my ground tag to 'GROUND', if condition does not work..**

```
void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "GROUND"){
        isGrounded = true;
        Jumping = false;
        anim.SetInteger("Status", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: please check this document OnCollisionEnter2D = > https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is not even being called. It is `OnCollisionEnter2D` not `onCollisionEnter2D`. Fix that and your problem should be solved.

*Not related to your problem*, but it is more efficient to use the `CompareTag` function to compare tags. So your `if (other.gameObject.tag == "GROUND")` should be   `if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("GROUND"))`

Answer (score 1):

Try using CompareTag() to check the tag of the gameObject.

```
void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("GROUND")){
        isGrounded = true;
        Jumping = false;
        anim.SetInteger("Status", 0);
    }
}
```